# Getting the nearest point while ignoring polygon in OpenLayers 6

Tags: openlayers

I have a map that contains one single layer with multiple feature. Those feature contains polygon and point.
I do not filter them because I did load every layout in the same object like the following

```
geoJsonObject = MyGeoJsonFile

const vectorSource: VectorSource = new VectorSource({
  features: new GeoJSON().readFeatures(geojson),
})

this.vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
  map: this._map, // Already generated map
  source: vectorSource,
})
```

Now I try to find the nearest point and move to it while the user is moving
_*geolocationService.onUserPositionChanged$ give me the user coordinates {lng: string, lat: string}*

```
moveToCoordinate(coordinates: any[], zoom: number = 16) {
  this.view.animate({ center: olProj.fromLonLat(coordinates), zoom: zoom })
}

this._geolocationService.onUserPositionChanged$
  .pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll))
  .subscribe((coordinates) => {
    if (coordinates) {
      const formattedCoordinates = [coordinates.lng, coordinates.lat]
      const fromLonLatCoordinates = olProj.fromLonLat(formattedCoordinates)

      this.positionFeature.setGeometry(coordinates ? new Point(fromLonLatCoordinates) : null)

      const nearestPoint: Feature = this.vectorLayer
        ?.getSource()
        .getClosestFeatureToCoordinate(fromLonLatCoordinates)

      if (nearestPoint) {
        this.moveToCoordinate(nearestPoint.getGeometry().getCoordinates(), 18)
      }
    }
  })
```

But `nearestPoint` will give me back the coordinate of the polyline instead of the point.
I know that `getClosestFeatureToCoordinate()` [does accept a filter](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Vector-VectorSource.html#getClosestFeatureToCoordinate) but I cannot figure out how to make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your filter function you can check feature geometry type and return `true` if geometry is `Point`:

```
function featureFilter(feature) {
  return(feature.getGeometry().getType() == 'Point');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone want to copy my code for centering to a specific location, I'll also had to change the projection like this. and I did write a shorter form of the method.

```
const nearestPoint: Feature = this.vectorLayer
  ?.getSource()
  .getClosestFeatureToCoordinate(fromLonLatCoordinates, (feature) => {
    return feature.getGeometry().getType() == 'Point'
  })
  
if (nearestPoint) {
  this.moveToCoordinate(
    olProj.transform(
      nearestPoint.getGeometry().getCoordinates(),
      this._map.getView().getProjection(),
      'EPSG:4326',
    ),
    18,
  )
}
```